# Constituents of LaI2

Tags: crystal-structure, halides, conductivity

An ionic solid $\ce{LaI2}$ shows electrical conduction due to presence of which anions and cations?

Comment: Note that questions looking like homework/test/exam/lab tasks, posted without *significant* attempts to understand/resolve them, are *explicitly off-topic* on this site and will be closed. 
// Review the guide [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Asking FAQs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Comment: You will never find out, short of knowing its formula.

Comment: [It is an electride, actually having a chemical formula of $\ce{La^{3+}[(I^−)_{2}e^{−}]}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanthanum_diiodide)

Comment: So it is neither due to cations nor anions, after all.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by Nilay, the electrical conductivity does not come from atomic ions but from electrons that are transfered from lanthnum into a delocalized conduction band rather than to the iodine. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanthanum), lanthanum also forms a monoiodide ($\ce{LaI}$) and a dihydride ($\ce{LaH2}$) with similar ionic/metallic mixed bonding. All these compounds have lanthanum(III), with the balancing negative charge from the nonmetal combined with conduction electrons (e.g. $\ce{LaI2}$ has two iodide ions plus one conduction electron per lanthanum(III) ion). Both the iodides and the hydride can be combined with more of the nonmetal to form $\ce{LaI3}$ or $\ce{LaH3}$, with loss of electrical conductivity as the additional nonmetal atoms capture the otherwise-conduction electrons.